# How to exit MsgBox when user press's cancel

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a small project at the moment in visual basic, it is a student and staff booking system that can be used for schools, colleges etc.
I am stuck on my "Log Out" function, I want the program to log out only when the user press's  "OK" on the MsgBox, but with the code I currently have the program still logs out even when the user press's "Cancel" inside the MsgBox.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub HomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HomeToolStripMenuItem.Click

    ''Calls upon sub function stored in form 1 to log out the program and close its forms.
    MsgBox("Are you sure you want to log out?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)

    If DialogResult.OK Then
        Form1.LogOut()
    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see I have used an If statement to log out the program if the user press's "OK" on the MsgBox, but if the user press's "Cancel" it still logs out anyway, any suggestions?

P.S. I am very new to VB so forgive any rookie mistakes or code inefficiencies :)

Comment: MsgBox() is a *function*.  It has a return value.  The code is not checking it.

Comment: And because _If DialogResult.OK Then_ is always true you call the Logut method

Comment: VB.NET is very different than vba and/or VB6.  The tags include words indicating when each is appropriate.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do it like this

```
 If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to log out?", "Titel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    Form1.LogOut()
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you Proxy Hacker, worked like a charm! :D One question, what does Windows.Forms do, what is the need for that piece of code and why would a simple" = DialogResult.Cancel" not work?

Comment: More about Windows.Forms https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx                                                                               More about the  "= DialogResult.Cancel " https://pastebin.com/ejfvVSzT

Comment: Logic is `If  MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to log out", ...) = DialogResult.OK` then log out... Not `DialogResult.Cancel`. Or change the meaning of the message like "Press cancel to log out".